# Criptografar / Descriptografar ID de autoincrement do MYSQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, criptografia

Preciso criptografar/descriptografar o ID original do MySQL impresso no HTML, para posteriormente reverter e receber o ID original no back-end.

Ex:

```
$var = $arr['id']; // 120

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Logradouro tal e tal, 123</td>
    <td> <button class='excluirRegistro' data-id='<?php echo $var; ?>'>Excluir</button> </td> // data-id='120'
  </tr>
</table>
```

Gostaria de criptografar para algo do tipo:

```
$varCrypt = funcao( $var, 'crypt' ); // 012980123324312

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Logradouro tal e tal, 123</td>
    <td> <button class='excluirRegistro' data-id='<?php echo $var; ?>'>Excluir</button> </td> // data-id='012980123324312'
  </tr>
</table>
```

Posteriormente receber na variável:

```
$id = $_GET['idregistro']; // 012980123324312
$id = funcao( $id, 'decrypt' );
$id = "120"; // ID original
```

**O cenário é o seguinte, uma tabela com os registros de endereços cadastrados pelo usuário, com um botão relacionado para editar e excluir o registro.**

Comment: Tem muitas maneiras, mas provavelmente todas erradas. Numa aplicação normal ninguém deveria precisar disso, Provavelmente se alguém consegue usar o ID para fazer algo errado, é falta de checagem das permissões do usuário . Talvez ajudasse editar a questão e explicar o problema real que está tentando resolver, em vez da maneira que pensou que resolveria.

Comment: Se tem algo que possa ajudar no contexto da pergunta, agradeço. Como disse, preciso de um algum modo de criptografar o ID exibido no HTML e descriptografar o ID no back-end.

Comment: A melhor ajuda creio que seja desincentivar a perder tempo com um contorno que provavelmente não é solução real para o problema, pelas razões já mencionadas. Se o ID não pode ser visto, não deveria nem estar no HTML (seja ofuscado ou não). E provavelmente não é o caso de esconder, qualquer aplicação básica mostra os IDs pra deleção, edição, etc sem problema nenhum. Mas se for mesmo, eu realmente fico curioso pra saber o cenário de aplicação, pois as ultimas perguntas que pediam o mesmo partiam da premissa errada. Se a sua for diferente, realmente deve ser um cenário atípico.

Comment: Se estiver usando uma conexão segura (SSL) já está criptografando. Se for algo que ninguém pode saber não deveria ser mandado para um cliente.

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta, expliquei o cenário. Obrigado!

Comment: Realmente é o que eu tinha pensado, não há necessidade de ocultar nada nesse cenário. Basicamente o que precisa é verificar as permissões de quem está fazendo a operação de deleção e alteração naquele registro.

Comment: Vou continuar a usar o Cipher, não tinha pretensão de fazer uso de mais classes no código, pois sou paranoico com segurança, se algo der errado, que não seja através do meu código, que seja por falhas em servidor ou outros níveis, rs.

Comment: Acredito que o que você procura seria na verdade usar o que chamam de [UUID](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identificador_%C3%BAnico_universal) (Universal Unique Identifier), algo parecido com esse token que resolveu usar. Dê uma olhada na função [UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) no MySQL, pode ser que ache mais interessante usá-la.

Comment: @EliseuB., o que você quer é obfuscar o ID para não permitir que o usuário, por exemplo, derive informações do seu sistema, como número de pedidos, etc. Se for isso então, dependendo do contexto, é recomendado: https://philsturgeon.uk/http/2015/09/03/auto-incrementing-to-destruction/

Comment: Dá uma [olhada aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html), pode te ajudar.

Comment: Ivan Ferrer, conheço a maioria, mas creio que tudo ficou mal interpretado da forma que expus a minha pergunta, mas já era, segurança em diversas camadas implementadas e funcionando. Obrigado por tudo. Namaste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [resposta marcada correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/273727/15089) tem alguns erros, na minha opinião, que resolvi dar uma outra resposta.

---

O `mt_rand()` (e o `str_shuffle()`) é previsível, uma pessoa com acesso a algumas resposta poderá conseguir a seed utilizada, por exemplo usando o [UnTwister](https://github.com/altf4/untwister) ou o [PHP_MT_SEED Cracker](http://www.openwall.com/php_mt_seed/), fora outras diversas maneiras.

Seu código está publico, então algo como `(date('s') + date('i') * 10000)` é  inútil, afinal as chances dos nossos relógios estarem diferentes é desprezível.

O `strrev()` não irá adicionar nenhuma segurança, isso é pior do que o Cifra de Cesar, porque ela pelo menos tinha "alguma chave".

Quando você exectar o `SELECT`, como `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE token = $token`, você estará claramente vulnerável a timing-attack, um usuário poderá obter informações através do tempo consumido para executar as queries.

---

Uma solução seria criar dois identificadores e buscar por eles, sendo um deles comparado de maneira segura, com o hash_equals.

### Crie dois identificadores:

```
$pesquisar = random_bytes(8);
$confirmar = random_bytes(24);
$confirmar_hashed = hash("sha256", $confirmar, true);
```

Então insira ele no banco de dados, como:

```
INSERT tabela (`pesquisar`, `confirmar`) VALUES ($pesquisar, $confirmar_hashed)
```

O usuário deve receber os valores de `$pesquisar` e `$confirmar`, considerando que isto seja passado em URL, seria como:

```
seusite.com/?pesquisar=$pesquisar&confirmar=$confirmar
```

*Lembrando que ambos devem ser únicos, o `$pesquisar` tem a mesma capacidade de um int64, ou BIGINT no caso do MySQL.*

### Pesquise pelo valor:

Para pesquisar, utilize o `pesquisar` como parâmetro principal, tal como:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE pesquisar = $pesquisar
```

Então compare o `confirmar` usando o `hash_equals`, como:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT confirmar FROM tabela WHERE pesquisar = ?')
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['pesquisar']);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($confirmar_hashed);
$stmt->fetch();

if(hash_equals($confirmar_hashed, hash("sha256", $_GET['confirmar'], true)) === false){
    echo 'Valor de "confirmar" é incorreto';
}
```

Por mim isto seria minimamente seguro. Claro, pressupondo que esteja utilizando um sistema operacional seguro, o `random_bytes` se escora no `/dev/urandom`.

**EDIT (2020-08-22):** Após revisar, notei que não foi assumido que poderia haver um ataque de "somente-leitura". Modifiquei a resposta para assumir esta possibilidade. Foi adicionado o uso do `hash("sha256", ...)` para impedir um ataque de somente-leitura, como um *"Read-Only SQL Injection"*. Isto supõe que o atacante tenha alguma acesso de leitura aos bancos de dados, mas não de edição. Neste cenário e com o uso de `hash`, o invasor terá apenas acesso aos dados que são resultado de uma hash (o `$confirmar_hashed`), portanto ele não terá o valor original (o `$confirmar`). Na versão anterior, e nestas condições,o atacante teria acesso aos códigos, normalmente.

Comment: Inútil na minha aplicação, só se faz uso de mais código, e além de ter usado um número randômico, também fiz uso como se, você deve ter lido toda a conversa, o uso de cipher, com verificação de sessão do usuário e validações de token e de id de registro e id de usuário logado.

Comment: @EliseuB. O seu código usou um `mt_rand` (e o `date`, mas irei ignorar esse). O `mt_rand` é um mero PRNG não é um CSPRNG com é o `random_bytes`, e tanto o `/dev/urandom` quanto o `/dev/random` são um CSPRNG e ele é usado por tal função. O uso de encriptação, ao meu ver, é inutil. Exceto em dois casos: se utiliza encriptação com autenticação (garantida por um MAC, preferencialmente baseado em Carter-Wegman) e a chave está em posse do usuário. Ou, ao invés do usuário ter a chave, você armazene-a em um HSM programável. Fora dessas duas opções, não vejo vantagem alguma.

Comment: Sua resposta é interessante como exercício teórico (tanto que tem meu up desde a postagem) mas aqui é realmente overengineering, sequer há uma necessidade real. Tem uma "resposta-comentário" do cantoni sobre uma das poucas razões plausiveis pra fazer o que o OP disse, mas até somar um primo fixo grande resolveria para tirar os IDs da sequencia sem gerar esforço computacional significante. Para qualquer coisa muito mais complicada que isso não faz sentido nem se falar em autoincrement, como pedido na pergunta.

Comment: @Bacco , a minha resposta foi baseada na resposta do Eliseu, que foi excluído. Aquilo parecia outro contexto. Acho que no contexto do Cantoni parece que simplesmente gerar um número aleatório resolve, já que o problema é ser sequencial. No caso do Eliseu (a resposta) me parece algo como "autenticação". Particularmente, eu utilizo algo muito próximo do que escrevi acima para "esqueci a senha", nestes caso o próprio "código aleatório" é a segurança. Sobre o custo computacional, acho que Blake2/Blake3 são rápidos o suficiente.

Comment: Bom, desnecessário dizer que respostas devem ser baseadas na pergunta, mas de qq forma isso não muda o que comentei. Foi só uma observação mesmo, no caso aqui o meu up permanece levando em comsideração o aspecto geral (tou levando em consideração a época que foi postada). Apesar de para o caso da pergunta ser uma solução irreal, pode servir como referencia para outras pessoas pelo detalhamento (nos raríssimos - para não dizer quase inexistentes - casos em que isso for necessário).

Answer (score 5):

Sem ser rude, mas já sendo: se você consegue descriptografar alguma coisa, o seu algoritmo de criptografia é uma porcaria mesmo.

Os algoritmos de hoje, os mais seguros, são [**one-way**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function). Isso quer dizer que não dá pra voltar. Uma vez criptografado, não dá pra "descriptografar".

O que as aplicações fazem é comparar os hash do que é criptografado, se der um match okay, se não sinto muito.

O que você pode fazer, no máximo, é criptografar o ID que está sendo enviado no formulário. O hash gerado vai ser comparado com o hash guardado no banco de dados e aí você faz o que quiser. Lembre que você tem que usar as mesmas funções de criptografia.

Se você guardou o ID no banco de dados com SHA256, você deve encriptar o formulário com SHA256.

Em PHP:

```
<?php

$hash_id_do_formulario = hash("sha256", $_POST['id_do_formulario']);

// Procura no banco de dados pelo mesmo hash depois
$query = "DELETE FROM minha_tabela WHERE ID = :hash_formulario";

$statement = $minha_conexao_pdo->prepare($query);

$statement->bindParam(':hash_formulario', $hash_id_do_formulario);

$statement->execute();
```

Pesquise pela função [**hash**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) em PHP.

Descrição da documentação do PHP:

```
string hash ( string $algo , string $data [, bool $raw_output = FALSE ] )
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua opinião, mas faltou ler por completo o que havia solicitado, disse encriptar, não criptografar, ou seja, mascarar apenas o ID de modo que no back-end possa reverter e ler o ID original, e trata-se de autoincremento do mysql, conheço hash's e criptografia, mas o que perguntei foi encriptar/mascarar e reverter. PS: atualmente faço uso de cipher de 256bits e utiliza chave pública e privada e token para validar o encrypt/decrypt, não é porcaria, mas gostaria de algo mais simples, pois não é um projeto complexo que exige tanta segurança.

Comment: Desculpa pela SUA ignorância. Criptografar e encriptar são sinônimos, sendo que encriptar é um estrangeirismo (da palavra *encrypt*, inglesa). EDIT: leia o título do seu *post*.

Comment: Para um bom entendedor basta, tolice perder seu tempo com comentário sem relevância, foque na colaboração e não em alfinetadas, o nível está baixo.

Comment: @EliseuB. Eu não estou te alfinetando não. Nem te conheço! Isso aqui não é pessoal. Se seu argumento é tecnicamente falho, você quer que eu corrobore?

Comment: Não, ignore e pule pra próxima "colaboração", como você disse, nada pessoal, porém nada relevante. E falando em colaboração, há algum modo de trancar a pergunta, ou apenas excluir? Já resolvi meu problema com o code e não tem nada a agregar a outros usuários de fato.

Comment: Se você já resolveu seu problema, o ideal é respondê-la aqui mesmo. Você pode responder à sua própria pergunta e depois marcá-la.

Comment: desculpe mas acredito que seu conceito sobre criptografia esteja enganado quando você diz *"se você consegue descriptografar alguma coisa, o seu algoritmo de criptografia é uma porcaria mesmo"*
Existe a criptografia *hash*, cujo objetivo é não ser revertida, mas se fosse só assim, como você faria num canal de comunicação criptografada, um *ssl* por exemplo? você criptografa a mensagem e depois não pode descriptografar, nunca vai saber o que a outra ponta te mandou?

Answer (score 1):

Existem cenários onde obfuscar o ID pode fazer sentido. IDs sequenciais podem revelar muito do seu data set. Um exemplo é a Loja Integrada, que mostra o ID da compra no final. É um número sequencial que revela a quantidade de compras já realizadas em determinada loja específica. Um concorrente poderia fazer pequenas compras ao longo do tempo para saber como andam as vendas da loja concorrente.

Um outro exemplo seria uma URL com o ID do cliente. Alguém com acesso ao sistema poderia ficar "brincando" com os IDs para saber quantos clientes existem no banco de dados.

Este post descreve com mais detalhes: [Auto-Incrementing IDs: Giving your Data Away](https://philsturgeon.uk/http/2015/09/03/auto-incrementing-to-destruction/)

Além disso, mostra soluções para obfuscar os IDs em algumas linguagens, dentre elas PHP: [Tiny](http://Auto-Incrementing%20IDs:%20Giving%20your%20Data%20Away%20Blog%20Logo)

Note que, obviamente, precisa ser algo reversível, caso contrário, você mesmo não conseguirá receber o ID de volta e atualizar alguma informação baseado nele.